# Can someone help me prove these two limits? I need them for probability.

Tags: calculus, limits

$$1.\lim_{n \to \ +\infty} \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n^k}\left(1- \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-k}= \frac{e^{-1}}{k!}$$

$$2.\lim_{n \to \ +\infty} \binom{r}{k} \frac {(n-1)^{r-k}}{n^r}= \frac{2^{k}}{k!}e^{-2}$$ when $r=2n$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem, take a look, this gives you directly your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e^{-1} $$
and:
$$ \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-k} = \frac{1}{(n-1)^k}\binom{n}{k} = \frac{1}{k!}\cdot\frac{n}{n-1}\cdot\frac{n-1}{n-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{n-k+1}{n-1}. $$
Can you fill the gaps now, by considering that for any fixed $\alpha$, $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n-\alpha}{n-1}=1$?

Answer (score 0):

2. $$\binom{2n}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{n^k} \cdot \left(\frac{n-1}{n} \right)^{2n-k} = \frac{1}{k!} \cdot \frac{(2n-k+1)(2n-k+2)\cdot ... \cdot (2n)}{n^k} \cdot \left( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right)^{2n-k} \to \frac{1}{k!} \cdot 2^k \cdot e^ {-2}$$, because

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n^{b_n}=e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n-1)b_n}$$

when

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n =1\;,\;\; and\;\;\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n= \infty$$

and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n-k+p}{n}=2\;,\;\; for \;\;1\le p \le k$$